# Tomcat url rewrite fails with 404, but browsing directly returns a 200

Tags: tomcat, rewrite, tomcat7

I have a web application deployed in `webapps/appname` and I'm trying to add in rewrite rules to `example.org/appname-slow` to rewrite to `example.org/appname?delay=1`. I have the following in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>statusEnabledOnHosts</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>sysout:DEBUG</param-value>
    </init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the following in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite use-context="true">

    <rule match-type="regex">
        <from>^/appname-slow/(.*)$</from>
        <to type="forward" qsappend="true">/appname/$1?delay=1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

but when I go to the new url, I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /appname/
type Status report
message /appname/
description The requested resource is not available.
```

And going directly to `/appname/` works as expected.

In `context.xml` I have

```
<Context crossContext="true">
```

in `catalina.out` this is the log output

```
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: starting conf reload check
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: conf is not modified
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name test.example.org
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /appname-slow/
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /appname-slow/
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Rule 0 run called with /appname-slow/
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: matched "from"
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: found 1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.substitution.MatcherReplacer DEBUG: replaced sb is /appname/?delay=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleExecutionOutput DEBUG: needs to be forwarded to /appname/?delay=1
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: starting conf reload check
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: conf is not modified
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ServerNameMatcher DEBUG: looking for hostname match on current server name test.example.org
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: checking for status path on /appname/
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter DEBUG: processing request for /appname/
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: Rule 0 run called with /appname/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: IS not a split DNS problem? how is your hostname resolved on your workstation and server? Are different IP's? Do you have in your hosts file different configuration?

Comment: Hostname resolves to the same server on both sides, Host files are standard (empty except for localhost). Tomcat access logs shows the hit to /appname-slow and it returning a 404 internally.

Comment: My understanding `urlrewrite` is entirely interprocess and doesn't proxy out again.

Comment: As the re-write is expecting an index file to host the query string ... you might try adding a welcome file list

Comment: Hrm. So the rewrite won't follow the welcome list for the new target app location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at this with fresh eyes, I has the `to` rule set incorrectly for cross context forwarding.

Setting it to

`<to type="forward" qsappend="true" context="appname">/$1?delay=1</to>`

and it works correctly! Booya!